# Javascript statements are executing after return

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
    $.each(json.ids, function(i, v) {
        if ($("#user").val() === v.username) {
            if ($("#pw").val() === v.password) {
                window.location = '/menu.html';
                return; //THIS RETURN
            }
            $("#errorblock").text("incorrect password").show().fadeOut(1000);
            return false;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#errorblock").text("no user found").show().fadeOut(1000);
    });
```

json is a variable containing data in json format. The weird thing is that once you enter the nested if (`if ($("#pw").val() === v.password)`), the window will correctly change to menu.html but the words "incorrect password" or "no user found" will flash right before the window is changed. I can fix this problem in some workaround way but I'm curious as to why that would happen -- shouldn't the return just stop execution of the code? Is there some syntax (or other) error here that I should fix to prevent this?

Comment: In the case the condition is passed, the return is never executed, changing the location stops the execution, and loads a new page.

Comment: That `return` just returns from the `$.each()` callback, not the containing function.  The `$.each()` will continue processing the rest of the list.

Comment: return of function is happening from `each`'s callback function which will only return from one of callback and it will execute next `event.pre...` statement and also `incorrect...` if no password will match

Comment: oh okay! How to fully return from the `each` then?

Comment: you should try return false; instead of just return nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than performing your logic in the each, find the user first before processing.

```js
var username = $("#user").val();
var password = $("#pw").val();

//find the user based on their username
var user = $.grep(json.ids, function(user){
  return user.username === username;
});

//if you found a user, check their password
if (user.length) {
  if (user[0].password === password) {
    //redirect them for good case
    window.location = '/menu.html';
  } else {
    //show incorrect password message
    $("#errorblock").text("incorrect password").show().fadeOut(1000);
  }
} else {
  //no user found, do whatever
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#errorblock").text("no user found").show().fadeOut(1000);
}
```

I should note, however, that performing password validation on the frontend is a **very bad idea**.

Comment: Thanks! But I've just looked up grep and it appears that it changes the actual data of the array, which I want to leave alone. Am I misunderstanding/is it okay to use? And yes, I know haha, but I'm just doing this as a learning exercise.

Comment: `$.grep` is just a find on the array, returning a subset of the elements from the original list.  Yes, if those elements are not basic variable types, changing them would also affect the original array.  However, in this use case, nothing on the elements is being changed.  We are simply doing comparisons (===) so this is not a concern.

Comment: Depending upon your needed browser support, you could also potentially use filter to the same effect.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter